# Applying CSS to all flex-wrapped columns and not just the first column

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm attempting to style all "columns" rendered by using `display: inline-flex`, `flex-direction: column` and `flex-wrap: wrap`. Styles applied to the container (such as `border`) are not rendered in subsequent columns as can be seen in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dsek546L/23/).

In the fiddle supplied, I'd like to know how to have the #container styles applied to each column - in particular border (as background-color could just as easily be applied to nested divs).

Of course, a hacky solution (such as styling the nested divs' nth-child to have a border-top/bottom) could achieve the visual effect, but it's not dynamic. I need it to work regardless of the height set on the container div.

As far as I'm aware, there is no selector for styling the first element in a flex column or anything that specific, so is there a way to do this without resorting to JavaScript?

Comment: Did you consider using css grids instead of flexbox? Flexbox is meant to  create a single row / column. You seem to want to create multiple rows (a grid).

Comment: I reopened the question. You can't target each column with an arbitrary amount of items using CSS, for that you will need script.